# Check whether a MYSQL Query is null

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make if condition according to whether a query is null or not and print two different tables. following is my code.

```
$number_of_date= "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date
                    FROM emp_leaves
                    WHERE emp_id='$userID'
                      AND leave_category='Annual'
                      AND apply_year='$year'";
$number_date = mysql_query ($number_of_date);

if (($number_date == 'NULL'))
{

    $result2 = "SELECT * FROM leave_info
                  WHERE employment_type='permanent'
                    AND leave_type='annual'";
    $sql2 = mysql_query ($result2);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
       ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["leave_type"]?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["leave_count"]?></td>
      </td></tr><?php }
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_leaves
              WHERE emp_id='$userID'
                AND leave_category='Annual'
              ORDER BY leave_id DESC limit 1";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["leave_category"]?></td>
        <?php }?><?php
    while($row11 = mysql_fetch_array($number_date)) {
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $row11["number_of_date"]?></td><?php } } ?>
    </tr>
```

But, "If" condition is not work. What is the correct way of make that condition. Anyone please help me!

Comment: i have updated ans please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
    $number_of_date= "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date
                      FROM   emp_leaves
                      WHERE  emp_id='$userID' AND
                             leave_category='Annual' AND
                             apply_year='$year'";

    $res_qry     = mysql_query($number_of_date) 
                  or 
                  die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'.$number_of_date.
                                       ' <br/>'.mysql_error());

    $rowqry      = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry);
    $number_date = $rowqry ['number_of_date'];
```

now use, $number_date

```
    if (($number_date == '') || empty($number_date))
```

if the query returns NULL, normally PHP considers it as a empty..

you can also try  is_null()

Please be informed that mysql functions are deprecated and  not recommended.
USE MySQLi or PDO instead. have a reference from following queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: try to debug a query like in the answer and post the outcome. keep debug point in both condition with < echo > and try to debug it.

Comment: Thank u , now it s fine from this way,

Answer (score 2):

you can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  or [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) php function.

`if(isset($number_date))` or `if(empty($number_date))`

**EDIT**

take a look [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

so please try this.

`if (mysql_query ($number_of_date))` or in your code edit like this.

`if (($number_date == true))`

Comment: There is no any error, but condition is not work correctly

Answer (score 2):

Check wether query execute or  result have not a row

```
  if (!$number_date or count($number_date) < 1){
      if(mysql_error()){
          die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

`mysql_query($sql)` execute query and return a result,we need to check,query is executed or not using if condition `if($number_date)` means query executed,`if(!$number_date)` means query not executed

Comment: Fine, but execute only if condition always, not go the else statement,

Comment: only go to the else statement when your query executed and result is more than 1 row if you want to only check to query executed or not than remove  `count($number_date) < 1`

Comment: @Chathurika can you explain me mean of  "query is null" means return result have no value ??

Comment: It means, if the emp_leaves table not has any sum value of number of date, according to particular user ID.

Comment: `count($number_date)` show number of returned value if  0 means no value else that have some value

Comment: @Chathurika if always goes in the if condition it means result is 0 or your query is not executed plz write code in if   `die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());`

Comment: @Chathurika don't use `mysql` instead of use `mysqli`,`mysql` is deprecated and no more longer sported

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the line

```
if (($number_date == 'NULL'))
```

This will not work, as you're comparing the variable `$number_date` to the *string* `'NULL'`, not to the *value* **`NULL`**. In order to test whether `mysql_query ($number_of_date)` returns **`NULL`**, you need to use the function [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php), as

```
if (is_null($number_date))
```

Having said that, let me also say [***DO NOT USE THE*** `mysql_*` ***API!***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) This API is deprecated for a number of very good reasons; please migrate your code to use either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Both of these APIs provide prepared statements, which (among other things) provide a measure of protection against [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

From mysql_query() [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

So your check `== 'NULL'` is wrong. Function will return handle if query succeeded or `FALSE` otherwise. You can check if something was found by `!== false`. Any other answer here with `isset()`, `empty()` or `if (!$number_date)` are correct too.

Also, note that mysql extension in PHP is **deprecated**. Better use other extension like [mysqli or PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).